# How to show table record as table header? Ich

Tags: php, mysql

I have this 3 table :

Table "attribute" :

```
attribute_id | attribute_name
=============================
 123         | City
 456         | Phone
```

Table "contact" :

```
email         | name
==============================
nov@gmail.com | Novri
teb@gmail.com | Tebe
```

Table "attribute_contact" :

```
email         | attribute_id | value
=========================================
nov@gmail.com | 123          | London
teb@gmail.com | 456          | 555444333
```

Note : attribute_id & email in "attribute_contact" table is foreign key from 2 previous table.

Question : 

Using SQL Query, is it possible to get output like this example :

```
email              | City            | Phone
nov@gmail.com      | London          | NULL
teb@gmail.com      | NULL            | 555444333
```

*City & Phone are records from "attribute" table*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
AC.email,
CASE WHEN AT.attribute_name='CITY' THEN AC.value ELSE NULL END CITY,
CASE WHEN AT.attribute_name='Phone' THEN AC.value ELSE NULL END PHONE
FROM attribute_contact AC
INNER JOIN attribute AT ON (AC.attribute_id =AT.attribute_id)
```

Try above query.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also

1) Use CASE for select value according to attribute id.

2) Inner join to select data from both tables.

```
SELECT atc.email,
CASE WHEN atc.`attribute_id` = 123 then `value` else NULL END AS CITY,
CASE WHEN atc.`attribute_id` = 456 then `value` else NULL END AS Phone
FROM `attribute_contact` atc INNER JOIN attribute at ON atc.`attribute_id` = at.`attribute_id`
```